# como obtengo datos de un formulario en el front office de prestashop?

Tags: symfony3, prestashop

tengo un modulo en prestashop que se ancla en el hook de DisplayCustomerAccountForm
en otros módulos dentro de el método getContent para resivir datos de un formulario solo tenia que poner

`if(Tools::isSubmit('boton'){
$nombre = Tools::getValue('nombre');
}`

básicamente con eso dentro de getcontet puedo obtener los valores pero en un modulo que trabaja en el front office de prestashop no me funciona no entra a el post a el hook alguien tienen algún ejemplo de formulario que funcione en el front  office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(Tools::isSubmit('boton'){
  $nombre = Tools::getValue('nombre');
}
```

esto tienes que ponerlo en el hook `DisplayCustomerAccountForm`, No en `getconent`, eso solo es para las paginas d configuraciones de los módulos